# Convert string to function in python

Tags: python, string, function, module, getattr

I have a string coming from the database. This string is the name of a file .py  that is within a module. The structure is this:

```
files
├── file1.py
├── file2.py
└── __init__.py
```

The `file1.py` contain:

```
def file1(imprime):
    print(imprime)
```

The `file2.py` contain:

```
def file2(imprime):
    print(imprime)
```

I need to convert the string to a function that can be callable.

In `main.py` file I try:

```
import files
string = "file1.py"
b = getattr(file1, string)

text = 'print this...'

b(text)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I dont understand the question ... also string is a terrible variable name :P

Comment: Why not just do, `import file1; b = file1.file1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the import function to import the module by name and stick that on the files module.

Edit: Changes to show how to call the function

```
import os
import files
wanted_file = "file1.py"
# name of module plus contained function
wanted_name = os.path.splitext(wanted_file)[0]
# if you do this many times, you can skip the import lookup after the first hit
if not hasattr(files, wanted_name):
    module = __import__('files.' + wanted_name)
    setattr(files, wanted_name, module)
else:
    module = getattr(files, wanted_name)
fctn = getattr(module, wanted_name)
text = 'print this...'
fctn(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems.  The `string` in this case shouldn't be ".py" file name but instead be a module or function name, so `file1`.

`file1` isn't in scope though, because you've imported `files`, and `file1` the function is inside `files.file1` the module.

You could have files/**init**.py declare the following:

```
from file1 import *
from file2 import *
```

If you want the `file1` function and the `file2` function to exist on `files`.  Then you would do `b = getattr(files, string)`.